# Is there a simple way to check unsafe expression in C++?

Tags: c++, exception, null-check

I'm trying to find a [better] way to run/check a potentially unsafe expression or perform multiple null checks in a more elegant way.

Here is an example of codes I would like to improve:

```
if (myObjectPointer &&
    myObjectPointer->getSubObject() &&
    myObjectPointer->getSubObject()->getSubSubObject() &&
    myObjectPointer->getSubObject()->getSubSubObject()->getTarget()) {

  // Use safely target
  ... *(myObjectPointer->getSubObject()->getSubSubObject()->getTarget()) ...
}
```

I tried to find a more elegant way to achieve this (instead of the above verbose null checks). Here is my first thoughts:

```
template<typename T>
bool isSafe(T && function) {
   try {
       function(); 
       // Just running the func above, but we could e.g. think about returning the actual value instead of true/fase - not that important. 
       return true;
    }
    catch (...) {
       return false;
    }
}

...
// And use the above as follow :
if(isSafe([&](){ myObjectPointer->getSubObject()->getSubSubObject()->getTarget(); })) {
    // Use safely target
}
...
```

The problem with the above is that we can't catch signals (Segmentation fault, ...). And I obviously don't want to handle all signals in the program, but only in this very specific check/eval function.

I'm I tackling the problem the wrong way ? Any other recommendations ? or the verbose if is inevitable ?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you control the source material?  If so I would suggest switching to returning references.  Those can't be null. (well not legally)

Comment: Agree with @NathanOliver re references to eliminate that downstream defensive coding.  Also, a remedy for too much defensive coding is the judicious use of assertions.

Comment: Looks like you have a bigger design issue. Your code needs to know the implementation details of that stack of nested objects down to the smallest detail. Try to rethink your hierarchy so you can end up with myObjectPtr->getTarget().

Comment: It seems you're looking for the C++ equivalent to the [C# null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-). Hmmm. I don't know if such a thing can be replicated.

Comment: Could have something like `safeExecute(myObjectPointer, &ObjectPointer::getSubObject, &SubObject::getSubSubObject, &SubSubObject::getTarget);`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: No, some (if not most) are from external lib (therefore can't modify them)^^

Comment: @WilliamClements assertions will raised core dumps right ? is that a best practice in prod code ?

Comment: @Mat I agree, but can't modify the lib managing those objects (and can't trust it neither)

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks - I'll also dig that option. I'll check if there is a way to dynamically apply "menber function" ObjectPointer::getSubObject to an instance of ObjectPointer.

Comment: @Abs there is more than one way to define "assertions" tailored to your environment. I work on production code that uses a few assertion styles, including some "fatal" assertions. They can be a good practice in prod code, yielding better focused crash reports.

Comment: I have a feeling that this a symptom of a design issue. If the class does not represent a data structure, e.g. a graph, you encode knowledge about the internal structure of the class when descending down the sub-object paths.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking about this, and like Jarod42 said, there must be some variadic template stuff. I'm not the best at this, but came up with this:

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, typename MemFn, typename... Params> 
void safeExecute(T* ptr, MemFn memFn, Params&&... params) {
    if (ptr != nullptr)
        safeExecute(std::invoke(memFn, ptr), std::forward<Params>(params)...);
}

template <typename T, typename MemFn>
void safeExecute(T* ptr, MemFn memFn) {
    if (ptr != nullptr) std::invoke(memFn, ptr);
}


struct Target {
    void Bar() { std::cout << "tada!\n"; };
};


template<typename T>
class Object {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> ptr;
public:
    Object() : ptr(std::make_unique<T>()) {}

    T* Get() { return ptr.get(); }
};

using SubSubObject = Object<Target>;
using SubObject = Object<SubSubObject>;
using MyObject = Object<SubObject>;

int main() {
    auto myObjectPtr = std::make_unique<MyObject>();

    safeExecute(myObjectPtr.get(),
                &MyObject::Get,
                &SubObject::Get,
                &SubSubObject::Get,
                &Target::Bar);
}
```

---

edit:
I've been playing with the idea of having a more general return type, so I experimented with the option not to call the member function, but to return an std::optional pointer to the object. This lead me to the following code:

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

template <typename T, typename MemFn, typename... Params>
auto safeGetObject(T* ptr, MemFn memFn, Params&&... params)
    -> decltype(safeGetObject(std::invoke(memFn, std::declval<T>()), std::forward<Params>(params)...))
{
    if (ptr != nullptr) return safeGetObject(std::invoke(memFn, ptr), std::forward<Params>(params)...);
    return {};
}

template <typename T, typename MemFn>
auto safeGetObject(T* ptr, MemFn memFn) -> std::optional<decltype(std::invoke(memFn, std::declval<T>()))> {
    if (ptr != nullptr) return std::invoke(memFn, ptr);
    return {};
}

struct Target {
    int Bar(int a, int b) const noexcept {
        return a+b;
    };
};

template<typename T>
class Object {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> ptr;
public:
    Object() noexcept : ptr(std::make_unique<T>()) {}

    T* Get() const noexcept { return ptr.get(); }
};

using SubSubObject = Object<Target>;
using SubObject = Object<SubSubObject>;
using MyObject = Object<SubObject>;

int main() {
    auto myObjectPtr = std::make_unique<MyObject>();

    auto optionalTarget = safeGetObject(
        myObjectPtr.get(),
        &MyObject::Get,
        &SubObject::Get,
        &SubSubObject::Get);

    auto result = optionalTarget ? optionalTarget.value()->Bar(3, 4) : -1;
    std::cout << " result " << result << '\n';
}
```

Comment: That looks great... It answers to the _"I'll check if there is a way to dynamically apply "menber function" ObjectPointer::getSubObject to an instance of ObjectPointer"_ from above, thanks. I'll try that on a real use case.

Comment: Note that it can even be improved to handle extra parameters for final method and have a return type.

Comment: @Jarod42 yeah, I was thinking about that later. (In bed. Posted it just before I turned in). However, I cannot figure out what to return then if one of the pointers is a nullptr... Returning the default type constructor would not be correct. Throwing an exception is also not correct. So you would have to return a `std::optional`...

Comment: `std::optional` would be my choice too.

Answer (score 1):

Putting possible design issues aside, you could use [an extended version of `std::optional`](https://github.com/TartanLlama/optional). Since not all intefaces are under your control, you would have to wrap the functions were necessary into a free-function. Let's assume you can change the class `MyClass` of `myObjectPointer`, but not the classes of the sub-objects.

```
class MyClass  {
public:
    optional<std::reference_wrapper<SubObjectClass>> getSubObject();
};

optional<std::reference_wrapper<SubSubObjectClass>> getSubSubObject(SubObjectClass& s) {
    SubSubObjectClass* ptr = s.getSubSubObject();

    if (ptr) {
        return std::ref(s.getSubSubObject());
    } else {
        return {};
    }
}

optional<std::reference_wrapper<Target>> getTarget(SubSubObjectCLass& s) {
    ...
}
```

You can now write something like

```
optional<MyClass*>  myObjectPointer = ...;
myObjectPointer.and_then(MyClass::getSubObject)
               .and_then(getSubSubObject)
               .and_then(getTarget)
               .map( doSomethingWithTarget ):
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I might delete my previous answer, because I've been rethinking this, now considering using std::optional and chaining.
Your original

```
myObjectPointer->getSubObject()->getSubSubObject()->getTarget()
```

is not really reproducible, since `operator->()` cannot be static. But we can use another operator, like `operator>>()`. Thus:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>
#include <functional>

struct Target {
    int Bar(int a, int b) const noexcept { return a+b; };
};

template<typename T>
class Object {
private:
    T* const ptr;
public:
    Object(T* ptr) noexcept : ptr(ptr) {}
    T* Get() const noexcept { return ptr; }
};

using SubSubObject = Object<Target>;
using SubObject = Object<SubSubObject>;
using MyObject = Object<SubObject>;

template <typename T>
auto makeOptional(T* ptr) -> std::optional< std::reference_wrapper<T>> {
    if (ptr) return std::ref(*ptr);
    return {};
}

template <typename T, typename MemFn>
auto operator>> (std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>> optObj, MemFn memFn)
-> std::optional< std::reference_wrapper<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(std::invoke(memFn, std::declval<T>()))>>> {
    if (optObj) return makeOptional(std::invoke(memFn, *optObj));
    return {};
}


int main() {
    {
        //complete
        auto TargetPtr = std::make_unique<Target>();
        auto subSubObjectPtr = std::make_unique<SubSubObject>(TargetPtr.get());
        auto subObjectPtr = std::make_unique<SubObject>(subSubObjectPtr.get());
        auto myObjectPtr = std::make_unique<MyObject>(subObjectPtr.get());

        auto optionalMyObject = makeOptional(myObjectPtr.get());

        auto optionalTarget = optionalMyObject >> &MyObject::Get >> &SubObject::Get >> &SubSubObject::Get;

        auto result = (optionalTarget) ? optionalTarget->get().Bar(3, 4) : -1;

        std::cout << "result is " << result << '\n';
    }
    {
        // incomplete
        auto subObjectPtr = std::make_unique<SubObject>(nullptr);
        auto myObjectPtr = std::make_unique<MyObject>(subObjectPtr.get());

        auto optionalMyObject = makeOptional(myObjectPtr.get());

        auto optionalTarget = optionalMyObject >> &MyObject::Get >> &SubObject::Get >> &SubSubObject::Get;

        auto result = (optionalTarget) ? optionalTarget->get().Bar(3, 4) : -1;

        std::cout << "result is " << result << '\n';
    }
}
```

will work...
Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

---

edit:
I've also tried putting it in a wrapper class

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <optional>

struct Target {
    constexpr int Bar(int a, int b) const noexcept { return a + b; };
};

template<typename T>
class Object {
private:
    T* const ptr;
public:
    constexpr Object(T* const ptr) noexcept : ptr(ptr) {}
    constexpr T* Get() const noexcept { return ptr; }
};

using SubSubObject = Object<Target>;
using SubObject = Object<SubSubObject>;
using MyObject = Object<SubObject>;

template<typename T>
class ObjectWrapper {
private:
    std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>> optRefObj{};
public:
    constexpr ObjectWrapper(T* ptr) noexcept
        : optRefObj(ptr ? std::make_optional(std::ref(*ptr)) : std::nullopt)
    {}

    template<typename MemFn>
    constexpr auto operator>>(MemFn memFn) const noexcept {
        return ObjectWrapper<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(std::invoke(memFn, std::declval<T>()))>>
            (optRefObj ? std::invoke(memFn, *optRefObj) : nullptr);
    }

    constexpr operator bool() const noexcept { return optRefObj.has_value(); }

    constexpr T* Get() noexcept { return optRefObj ? &optRefObj->get() : nullptr; }
};

int main() {
    {
        //complete
        auto const TargetPtr = std::make_unique<Target>();
        auto const subSubObjectPtr = std::make_unique<SubSubObject>(TargetPtr.get());
        auto const subObjectPtr = std::make_unique<SubObject>(subSubObjectPtr.get());
        auto const myObjectPtr = std::make_unique<MyObject>(subObjectPtr.get());

        auto const myObjWrp = ObjectWrapper(myObjectPtr.get());

        auto optionalTarget = myObjWrp >> &MyObject::Get >> &SubObject::Get >> &SubSubObject::Get;

        auto const result = optionalTarget ? optionalTarget.Get()->Bar(3, 4) : -1;

        std::cout << "result is " << result << '\n';
    }
    {
        // incomplete
        auto const subObjectPtr = std::make_unique<SubObject>(nullptr);
        auto const myObjectPtr = std::make_unique<MyObject>(subObjectPtr.get());

        auto const myObjWrp = ObjectWrapper(myObjectPtr.get());

        auto optionalTarget = myObjWrp >> &MyObject::Get >> &SubObject::Get >> &SubSubObject::Get;

        auto const result = optionalTarget ? optionalTarget.Get()->Bar(3, 4) : -1;

        std::cout << "result is " << result << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: by the way, gotta love that return type deduction guide xD