# operator >> is not defined why?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm trying to help with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58598168/is-there-a-simple-way-to-check-unsafe-expression-in-c), and I think I found a nice solution. But it's kind of complex due to all the wrapping I need. 
I would want to overload `operator>>` to allow for easy chaining notation. But it's not working as I expected.

I can do:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class Object {
private:
    T* const ptr{ nullptr };
public:
    Object(T* ptr) noexcept : ptr(ptr) {}
    T* Get() const noexcept { return ptr; }
};

using MyObject = Object<int>;

template <typename T, typename MemFn>
auto fnc (T* ptr, MemFn memFn)
-> decltype(std::invoke(memFn, std::declval<T>())) {
    if (ptr) return std::invoke(memFn, *ptr);
    return nullptr;
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<MyObject> myObjectPtr = std::make_unique<MyObject>(nullptr);
    [[maybe_unused]] int* optionalTarget = fnc(myObjectPtr.get(), &MyObject::Get);
}
```

*However*, I want to do

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class Object {
private:
    T* const ptr{ nullptr };
public:
    Object(T* ptr) noexcept : ptr(ptr) {}
    T* Get() const noexcept { return ptr; }
};

using MyObject = Object<int>;

template <typename T, typename MemFn>
auto operator>> (T* ptr, MemFn memFn)
-> decltype(std::invoke(memFn, std::declval<T>())) {
    if (ptr) return std::invoke(memFn, *ptr);
    return nullptr;
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<MyObject> myObjectPtr = std::make_unique<MyObject>(nullptr);
    [[maybe_unused]] int* optionalTarget = myObjectPtr.get() >> &MyObject::Get;
}
```

What does work, but what I consider ugly is

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <optional>

template<typename T>
class Object {
private:
    T* const ptr{ nullptr };
public:
    Object(T* ptr) noexcept : ptr(ptr) {}
    T* Get() const noexcept { return ptr; }
};

using MyObject = Object<int>;

template <typename T>
auto makeOptRef(T* ptr) -> std::optional< std::reference_wrapper<T>> {
    if (ptr) return std::ref(*ptr);
    return {};
}

template <typename T, typename MemFn>
auto operator>> (std::optional<std::reference_wrapper <T>> ptr, MemFn memFn)
-> std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(std::invoke(memFn, std::declval<T>()))>>> {
    if (ptr) return makeOptRef(std::invoke(memFn, *ptr));
    return {};
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<MyObject> myObjectPtr = std::make_unique<MyObject>(nullptr);
    std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<MyObject>> myObjOptRef = makeOptRef(myObjectPtr.get());

    std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<int>> optionalTarget = myObjOptRef >> &MyObject::Get;

    [[maybe_unused]] int output = (optionalTarget) ? optionalTarget->get() : -1;
}
```

Comment: The code you've shown is not consistent with your description - neither example would compile, let alone "work".    If one works for you and the other doesn't, the explanation is in the differences between your actual code and what you have posted.   Read up on providing a [mcve].    Also, it is not possible to invoke or call a member function of a class on anything other than an instance (or pointer to an instance) of that class - if that is forced, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: "_overloaded `operator>>` must have at least one parameter of class or enumeration type_"

Comment: @Peter Neither will compile or work? [I beg to differ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8ViqVmx59R80ZMo2).. I mean, do you want copy-past code or such?

Comment: I would argue that you're also overusing `auto`.  Using it for `std::unique_ptr<MyObject>` is one thing, but for `int *`?  That actually made it harder to read the code... I had to spend mental cycles on deducing what type `optionalTarget` was.

Comment: @MarkStorer I'm an AAA guy. will fix for clarity

Comment: American Automotive Association?!

Comment: @MarkStorer [Almost Always Auto](http://cginternals.github.io/guidelines/articles/almost-always-auto/)

Answer (score 8):

Any pointer type is a built-in type, as are pointers to members. You are trying to overload an operator for two built-in types, that's simply a non-starter. At least one argument must be of a user-defined type, or a reference to it.

You can get it to work by passing a `T&` instead of a `T*`.

Comment: hmmm, I was afraid of that... Passing a T reference will lead to problems if the `nullptr` is returned. then I will need an std::optional again... which needs a std::reference_wrapper.... and I'm back to the terrible code I had before...
Is there any way to get a chaining with operators?

Comment: @JHBonarius - Well, you can always assume `T&` refers to a smart pointer object. That should be a user-defined type. Then chain the pointer without a call to `get()`.

Comment: Yeah, so the OP of the original question is working with legacy code... not having any smart pointers...

Comment: I'm still trying to figure this out. How can I realize this for raw pointers... what to do with a T& when T* = nullptr? I can't find a better solution then std::optional. So I cannot accept your answer as "You can get it to work by passing a T& instead of a T*." is not true for me...

Comment: @JHBonarius - You are under no obligation to accept any answer.